# eslint not linting though server is running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, eslint

I downloaded a frontend template online and yarn installed all packages and an .eslint.json file does exist and the extension is installed in Visual Studio Code but it does not show any linting errors.

Here is my .eslint.json file

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["flowtype", "react"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "packageDir": "./" }],
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [
      "error",
      {
        "components": ["Link"],
        "specialLink": ["to"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "reactjs-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:auto": "mocha test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.jsx",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "flow-bin": "0.83.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
  }
}
```

here is my settings.json file

```
{
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "choseToUpdateConfiguration",
  "eslint.packageManager": "yarn",
  "javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
  "javascript.format.enable": false,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterCommaDelimiter": false,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": false,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements": false,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterSemicolonInForStatements": false,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeAndAfterBinaryOperators": false,
  "typescript.tsc.autoDetect": "off",
  "files.eol": "\n",
  "prettier.endOfLine": "lf",
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,

  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.lintTask.enable": true,

  "eslint.run": "onSave",
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true



}
```

The template I downloaded is a personal one for a company but here is the package.json to see what it entails

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I am using visual studio code

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What is the template you used? What are the packages that were installed (show the `package.json` file)? What are the plugins you installed?

Comment: @EmileBergeron I pasted the package.json file in the original question. Thank you

Comment: Can anyone help pls

Answer (score 0):

If and not missing something, to make it work follow or check you did the next steps:

- Download ESLint and Prettier extensions for VSCode if you didn't
- Install ESlint and Prettier libraries in your project `npm install -D eslint prettier` (or use yarn)
- Install eslint-config-prettier (disables formatting for ESLint) and eslint-plugin-prettier (allows ESLint to show formatting errors as we type) `npm install -D eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier`

After that and if all your dependencies are installed taking in consideration your eslintrc file, you should be able to restart vscode and see the errors in the editor directly.

Note that this is something "generic" and you may need to install more packages to add more validations.

Comment: @tony_h can you check if you really named your eslint config file like ".eslintrc.json"? Naming it as ".eslint.json" makes it unrecongizable by vscode by default

Comment: copied the file name directly here: .eslintrc.json

Comment: Could you please open in vscode "User Settings" and write in the search bar "eslint validate"? There you will see some languages to be used by the linter, make sure the ones you need are checked

Comment: Also try doing "command + shift + p" and writing "eslint enable". Then, press enter to make sure the linter is enabled. Restart after that too.

Comment: I edited and pasted the settings.json file for you to see